# Disable WebFaultClientMessageInspector in WCF Client?

Tags: wcf

I'm using WCF to invoke a remote REST API, and am getting a 500 Internal Server Error from the service.  Using Fiddler, I can see the body of the 500 response (which includes, buried in HTML, the reason for the 500 error).  I would like to be able to examine the response body in .Net, but it appears that the WebFaultClientMessageInspector gets there first, and throws a vague exception.

[image]

Is there anyway to disable/override this inspector (and see the full response body)?

Comment: You are using try and catch?

Comment: Yes, but the exception doesn't have any information about the actual payload coming back in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured this out - I do need a custom message inspector (IClientMessageInspector), but I also need to configure it FIRST in my WCF Endpoint configuration:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="myCustomErrorWebHttp">
    <myCustomnClientBehavior />
    <webHttp />
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

Doing THIS caused my inspector to be triggered BEFORE WebFaultClientMessageInspector, and I was able to inspect the message body.

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.co.il/2011/06/show-exception-details-on-client-side.html)

> How to solve this problem? The answer is obvious: create custom
>   implementation IClientMessageInspector and use it on client.

Full details is in the link.

Comment: I've tried this, but it looks like WebFaultClientMessageInspector is registered with the webHttp behavior by default, and it raises the exception before my custom IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply gets a chance to intervene?  I can step through my custom handler's BeforeSendRequest invocation, but AfterReceiveReply is never called (because of the exception thrown by WebFaultClientMessageInspector).,

Comment: What about catch all unhandled exceptions thrown by WCF ?? Maybe that can catch your error.

Comment: http://johannblais.blogspot.com/2009/02/handling-exceptions-right-way-in-wcf.html